# Trying to Query RavenDB Entity with a Collection via Index

Tags: ravendb

I have a RavenDB mvc applicaton that has a document entity called Member. Each Member document has a list of users that are considered administrators. Only they can view and manage that Member document. On one of the pages I have a member search and have created an index to assist in the search.

```
public class Members_ByName : AbstractIndexCreationTask<Member>
{
    public Members_ByName()
    {
        Map = members => from member in members select new {member.Title};
        Indexes.Add(x => x.Title, FieldIndexing.Analyzed);
        Sort(x => x.Title, SortOptions.String);
    }
}

public class UserReference
{
    public string Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
}

public class Member
{
    public string Id { get; set; }
    public string Title { get; set; }
    public ICollection<UserReference> Administrators { get; set; }
}
```

Since the user can only view/manage Member documents where they are an Administrator when I do the following to get the members

```
RavenQueryStatistics stats;
var query = RavenSession.Query<Member, Members_ByName>().Statistics(out stats);
query = query.Where(x => x.Title.StartsWith("anything"));
query = query.Where(x => x.Administrators.Any(y => y.Id == CurrentUser.Id)); 
var list = query.OrderBy(x => x.Title).Paging(CurrentPage, Configuration.DefaultPage, CurrentPageSize).ToList();
```

When the above code runs I get "The field 'Administrators_Id' is not indexed, cannot query on fields that are not indexed" which I understand but every thing I have attempted to get Administrator's Id in the index has not worked and not sure how to make it work at this point.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this:

```
    Map = members => from member in members
                     select new {member.Title, Administrators_Id = members.Administrators.Select(x=>x.Id)};
```